# REGO policy failing because variable is unsafe

Tags: opa, rego

Im exploring the use of OPA for a project whereby I need to validate some of the contents of JWT. However when I use this expression I get an unsafe error:

```
config := payload[1].main-application.configuration == "Demo Config"
```

```
1 error occurred: policy.rego:5: rego_unsafe_var_error: var application is unsafe
```

The issue seems to be that REGO is interpreting the - as a var.

Is there a way to escape this ?